# Como eu capturo dados de uma stream (Nome da musica, capa do álbum, nome da banda)?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, stream, áudio

Como poderia capturar os metadatas de uma stream de audio e colocar alguns dados como capa do álbum, nome da musica, e exibir isso na minha activity.

Comment: Isso vai depender, você está usando servidor Shoutcast / Icecast para fazer transmissão ? Ou são apenas aquivos de audio?

Comment: A url que quero ler os dados é essa
 http://centova2.ciclanohost.com.br:10035/stream

Sou iniciante no android e não faço muita ideia de como fazer isso.

Comment: Veja se é isso que você quer [Como recuperar metadados do shoutcast no Android? ( Em Inglês )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638251/how-retrieve-metadata-from-shoutcast-on-android)